# 303 Redirect Only Works In Chrome?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, get

This is a problem I've been dealing with over the last couple days, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why a 303 redirect works in Chrome only. I created a post, redirect, get function to handle form data to avoid duplicate submissions if the page is refreshed.

```
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test-form/");
    die();
```

I just don't understand why this doesn't work outside a chrome browser. The end result it produces in firefox and safari is an empty form as if your\'re viewing the page for the first time. The session and post arrays appear to empty once hitting this block in firefox and safari.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the additional parameters to the header call. From the user comments on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#78470):

```
// 303 See Other
header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,303);
```

Comment: I just tried `header("Location: /test-form/",TRUE,303);
        die();` and it works in chrome, but not firefox.